# Flutter ListView with nested ListView throws RangeError for offscreen widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

First time working in Flutter and not really a software wizard. I've built an app that connects to Firebase and retrieves a data structure as a Map (all after login). This works fine. However, the data is (kind of) a list of lists (or Map of Maps), etc. Basic structure is:

```
{
title1: {
      item-A: {
               0: line1,
               1: line2,
               2: line3,
              },
      item-B: {
               0: line1,
               1: line2,
               2: line3,
              }
        },
title2: {
      item-A: {
               0: line1,
...
}
```

The schema can have more or fewer titles, items, and lines, but the structure is the same.

The code I've implemented gets the values from the database (Firebase Realtime Database) via FutureBuilder, formats the results, and displays them. Retrieving the results and the general display formatting works as intended, but I can only see one or two of the list widgets before a huge red box is displayed and I get the following error:

```
The following IndexError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1
```

If I run a Hot Refresh or Hot Reload, or just reload the browser, I get a few more rows of Widgets and the error changes to the next index increment:

```
The following IndexError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 4: 5
```

If I keep refreshing, eventually the whole list shows up and the error goes away. Obviously this is not the desired behavior, however. I've been working this and testing different approaches but I don't really understand what the issue is.

My code (with a couple of details left out) is as follows:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ApplicationState>(
        builder: (context, appState, child) {
          selectedIndex.add(-1);

          return Scaffold(
              ...
              body: FutureBuilder(
                future: futureDataRetreiverFunction(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
                  ... // convert the snapshot.data here // 
                  return Container(
                      ...
                      child: ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: [
                            Form(
                            key: _formKey,
                            child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  ListView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    controller: ScrollController(),
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: snapshotData.keys.length, // the data is a Map
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                      Column(
                                          children: [
                                            ...
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Text(snapshotData.keys.elementAt(index)),
                                              ]
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Text(selectedIndex[index].toString())
                                              ]
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                              Flexible(
                                                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 10),
                                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                                      primary: false,
                                                      itemCount: snapshotData.values.elementAt(index)[1].length,
                                                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index2) =>
                                                        Text(snaptshotData.values.elementAt(index)[1][index2])
                                                    )
                                                  )
                                                )]
                                              )
                                            ])
                                           )
                                         ])
                                        ])
                                       );
...
```

Comment: what is  use of this code  selectedIndex.add(-1);  There is an error because listView is getting the index length but the actual data does not contain that much data. So check to see if you might get null data too.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. selectedIndex.add(-1); is used in other areas for a setState({selectedIndex(index)}); call, but that's all. It relates to the 1-5 boxes listed there. I've done debugPrint on all the data and it is all there (returned from Firebase Database), I am wondering if the rangeError is related to the ScrollView caching. OR maybe related to order-of-operations in the Widgets (having the FutureBuilder  inside the Scaffold, instead of vice-versa...

Comment: instead of debug point add uncaught exception point ad try to get exact code block issue.

Comment: No, you nailed it Vishal. The selectedIndex was building against an index list of 6 but I was only adding one list item. I changed that code to build a full list of 6 index points ,and... no problems. Worked. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ohh great. Okay just do one thing. update your solution with details in your answer and closed question so it will helps others. Happy coding:) Ohh great. Okay just do one thing. update your solution with details in your question and closed so it will helps others. Happy coding:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vishal pointed out the answer in his first comment to this question. I am using "selectedIndex" as part of a `setState({})` call to change some visuals as part of an `onTap: () {}` call. I was initiating the list with a simple initiation call earlier in the class (`List selectedIndex = [];`), but then was only adding 1 item to the index in the builder. However, in this case, there are a total of 6 items which get built (more/less in other scenarios), and that was throwing the index error. Which is why it would increment on reload (another `seletedIndex.add(-1);` was called). I dropped in a quick function to pre-populate the index based on the size of the snapshot data, along the lines of:

```
for (var counter=0; counter<snapshotData.keys.length; counter++) {
    selectedIndex.add(-1);
}
```

This solved the index RangeError.